# Default users for MySQL 8 installation on Linux

Tags: mysql

A fresh install of MySQL 8 on Linux yields the following default users for us:

```
debian-sys-maint
mysql.infoschema
mysql.session
mysql.sys
root
```

After creating our own users, with the correct privileges, we are thinking of deleting all the users, other than root (i.e. `debian-sys-maint, mysql.infoschema, mysql.session and mysql.sys`).

---

**Q)** Is it okay to delete the default users, other than root, or will there be any unexpected surprises if we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, there will be some unexpected surprises if you delete reserved accounts**

**You should not remove reserved accounts.** All accounts has special purpose. All these reserved accounts are locked so that they cannot be used for client connections.

Check `MySQL-8` docs on [reserved accounts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reserved-accounts.html)